# Wikidata Query Service, filtering for values/string that lay above/below a certain value

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata-query-service

I made a query, that shows all items that are 'found in taxon' 'Chlamydia trachomatis D/UW-3/CX'. These items must have the Properties P644 (genomic start) and P645 (genomic end). So far this works. But then I wanted to filter these items depending on the values of 'genomic start' and 'genomic end'. In my example I wanted to recieve all items, where 'genomic start' is higher than '100' and 'genomic end' is lower than '3000'. But it did not work. Am I not using FILTER the right way?

Here is my code directly in the Wikidata Query Service Page:
[Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ps%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20pq%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0A%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fsubject%20%3FsubjectLabel%20%3Fgenomic_start%20%3Fgenomic_startLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fsubject%20wdt%3AP703%20wd%3AQ20800373.%20%23P703%3A%20found%20in%20taxon%3B%20Q20800373%3A%20Chlamydia%20trachomatis%20D%2FUW-3%2FCX%3B%0A%20%20%09%3Fsubject%20wdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ7187.%09%09%23P279%3A%20subclass%20of%3B%20Q7187%3A%20gene%3B%0A%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fgenomic_start%20%3E%20%22100%22%29.%0A%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fgenomic_end%20%3C%20%223000%22%29.%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20200%0A)

```
SELECT ?item ?genomic_start ?genomic_end
Where{
?item wdt:P703 wd:Q20800373. #P703:found in taxon
?item wdt:P644 ?genomic_start.
?item wdt:P645 ?genomic_end.
FILTER (?genomic_start > "100").
FILTER (?genomic_end < "3000").
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first convert the value to int in order to be able to use > or <:

```
SELECT ?item ?genomic_start ?genomic_end
Where{
?item wdt:P703 wd:Q20800373. #P703:found in taxon
?item wdt:P644 ?genomic_start.
?item wdt:P645 ?genomic_end.
FILTER (xsd:integer(?genomic_start) > 100).
FILTER (xsd:integer(?genomic_end) < 3000). 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your answer is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I'd argue that Wikidata is broken in this case since it's storing a number as a string. The conversion shouldn't be necessary.